# Microsoft Emotion API can i use it to create application for pc in visual studio with python?

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to build an app with microsoft-cognitive emotion API, as python is my preferred programming language just wanted to know if this could be done in visual studio would love to learn more about it.

Answer (score 1):

There is python code available on GitHub that demonstrates calling the Emotion API: https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Emotion-Python. It comes in the form of a Jupyter notebook, but it should be a good place to get started nonetheless.